# CarrierWave uploading files to upload folder after changing storage to dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to store files on Dropbox.I have successfully integrated everything. Files are being successfully stored on Dropbox. **The issue is CarrierWave still storing files on local machine app folder**.
And there i am getting error

> Permission denied @ unlink_internal -
>   C:/Users/name/Desktop/app_name/public

Previously i had this in my configuration file

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
end
```

After that i changed it to:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :dropbox
end
```

I am using windows 8 and i am in development mode. I am keen to know why files are still being stored locally despite changing storage to dropbox.
**See here** [Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvfrx.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3. getting Errno::EACCES Permission Denied when uploading files on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854725/rails-3-getting-errnoeacces-permission-denied-when-uploading-files-on-product)

Comment: But i don't want to upload files locally.

Comment: did you try the solution there?

Comment: I have updated my question, On windows those commands not work

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem when I was uploading to AWS s3. The solution below worked for me:

In `config\initializers\carrierwave.rb`, add the following line:

```
config.delete_tmp_file_after_storage = false
```